# Rounded corner of left and right side not correct

Tags: ios, swift, rounded-corners

I am working or project in which I have to give corner to view from top left and top right. I am using autolayout for it. My view width is 296. Here is design

[image: first cell]

as per my design in first cell of tableview here my code to rounded corner of **selected** **view**

```
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let  view_  = cell.viewWithTag(10)! as UIView
 let maskLayer : CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let maskpath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view_.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft,.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10, 10))
            
            maskLayer.frame = view_.bounds;
            maskLayer.path = maskpath.CGPath;
            
            view_.layer.mask = maskLayer
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            return cell
```

But my problem is I am getting this output

[image]

I give `view_.bounds` but I dont know why it takes original frame value of that view. In small device like iphone 4s and 5, it gives output perfectly but in big device its getting problem like in screeshot.

Please help me with it

Comment: just reload your table in viewdidload() method your problem solve

Comment: define the frame of the tableCellView in terms of the width of the device screen as view.frame.width*0.9

Comment: @MdIbrahimHassan i have same issue but with bottom side only left side its work . right side its not show corner . and i m working in objective c

Comment: CAShapeLayer *rectShape1 = [[CAShapeLayer alloc]init];
            rectShape1.bounds = Borderview1.frame;
            rectShape1.position = Borderview1.center;
            
            rectShape1.backgroundColor = Lightbrowncolor.CGColor;
            rectShape1.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: Borderview1.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){5.0, 5.0}].CGPath;
            Borderview1.layer.mask = rectShape1;
 Borderview1.layer.masksToBounds = true;

Comment: @MdIbrahimHassan yeah giving new frame to view works

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are running your code *too soon*. Your code depends upon an assumption that we know `view_.bounds`:

```
let maskpath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view_.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopLeft,.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10, 10))
maskLayer.frame = view_.bounds;
```

But at the time your code runs, that value has not yet been finally determined. The thing to remember here is that views are *resized* as they placed into the interface. You want to postpone your code until *after* `view_.bounds` has achieve its final value (also known as *layout*).

Answer (score 0):

Define the frame of the tableCellView in terms of the width of the device screen as `UIScreen.main.bounds.width*0.9`